# Faulty htaccess File

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to allow any site or desktop app to call a script in one specific folder on my site. I have therefore put an `.htaccess` file in that directory. It is definitely being read, but I get the following errors in my Apache error log file:

```
[Sat Oct 14 21:57:01.943348 2017] [core:alert] [pid 3944:tid 1172] [client ::1:57586] C:/wamp64/www/mysite/phpgeneral/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost:52656/mysite/index.html
[Sat Oct 14 21:58:39.918523 2017] [core:alert] [pid 3944:tid 1164] [client ::1:57599] C:/wamp64/www/mysite/phpgeneral/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost:52656/mysite/index.html
```

This is my `.htaccess` file. **Should these commands have something wrapped around them?** Or is there something wrong in general (I am new to `.htaccess`).

```
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

Comment: No sure if **always** is relevant instead of **Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"**

Comment: Try loading headers_module inside Apache config

Comment: @user4035 - that did the trick. Put a one line answer and I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the headers_module inside Apache config